# Parsing JSON with RequestBody in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

So I've been having some issues with @RequestBody in Spring. I've had no problems at all when it comes to returning objects and having Spring automatically parse them. I have no issue if I only declare a String as an argument for the method. Here is the code, I'll begin with what I want to receive:

```
public class ToParse {

    private String name;

    ToParse() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Here is the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class ConcreteTestController implements TestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"application/json"})
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @Override
    public ToParse getSilly(@RequestBody ToParse toParse) {
        ToParse toReturn = new ToParse();
        toReturn.setName("stuff");
        return toReturn;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @Override
    public ToParse getSilly(String test) {
        ToParse toReturn = new ToParse();
        toReturn.setName(test);
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Note that the second method works just fine. The header I am sending in is "application/json" for the first method and the JSON is:

```
{
    “name”:”blablabla”
}
```

I get a 415 error when trying to call the first method using the rest client in intelliJ. My configuration is in XML and it is .

What am I doing wrong? There are many answers to these types of question but usually they are resolved by fixing header or Springconfig. I cannot see what I have done wrong.

Comment: You should specify

<mvc:annotation-driven /> 
 In your dispatcher servlet bean configuration file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting a *HTTP Error 415 Unsupported media type* because you are sending a `POST` request without adding the `Content-Type: application/json` header.

> The Content-Type entity-header field indicates the media type of the entity-body sent to the recipient

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17

[image: Adding Content-Type header in IntelliJ REST Client]